# php-fpm в отдельном docker-контейнере, подключение в nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm

Гуглил всяко, так и не понял как подключиться к php-fpm в docker-контейнере.
Всё кроме php-fpm у меня пока на машине без контейнеров.
Хотел без docker-compose, только с самим docker запустить (запустилось, работает) php-fpm и подключиться к нему в nginx который без контейнера, но не понял как это делается и вообще возможно ли сделать так чтобы php-fpm шел отдельным контейнером, и nginx тоже отдельным.

Comment: Пробовал docker run -d -p 9000:9090 --name php-fpm php:7.4-fpm, и в nginx fastcgi_pass localhost:9000; но это не сработало

Answer (score 0):

Уже разобрался.
Команда fastcgi_pass принимает аргумент вида localhost:9000.
Пробросил порт 9000 и подключился.
Заодно и директорию примонтировал.

```
fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;

docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --mount type=bind,source=/home/user/sites/docker-test,destination=/home/user/sites/docker-test --name php-fpm php:7.4-fpm
```

Comment: ошибочка, это не работает, я перепутал порты просто